# How to fix syntax error when printing a string with an apostrophe in it?

Tags: python, syntax-error, apostrophe

When I am trying to print a string like the one below which uses an apostrophe in the sentence,

```
print(''I am jack's raging bile duct'')
```

I get a syntax error. How to fix this?

Comment: You can also use `'''` or `"""` if you absolutely hate backslashes (as you should :). ie. `'''"Isn't this cool?"'''`

Answer (score 33):

You can use both `"` and `'` to write a string in Python, a double `'` (`''`) will be invalid.

If you use `"`, the syntax for your case would be

```
print("I am jack's raging bile duct")
```

But if you use `'`, you may need to escape the apostrophe as follows:

```
print('I am jack\'s raging bile duct')
```

In general, if you use `"`, and your string has also `"`, you will need to escape every `"` in your string, except the one that closes, same happens with `'`.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways:

```
print('I am jack\'s raging bile duct')
```

or:

```
print("I am jack's raging bile duct")
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use double `'`, use `"`.

```
print("'I am jack's raging bile duct'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of double quotes will do the trick. print("I am jack's raging bile duct")
I tried it and works good. 
Happy coding!

Comment: This is the same as what's already mentioned in earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is not a double quote.
You want `"`.

Answer (score -3):

you have 3 way:

- """ it's python """
- " it's python "
- ' it\'s python '

in general you just can use different of mark
it maean use " in ' OR use ' in ".

Comment: I think the other 5 answers also contain this information. What is new in this answer?

Comment: Hi 
I took all together.
because it's easier to see.
but you're right, i will correct my work